# Using Resource Dictionaries in a Class Library

Tags: wpf, flowchart

I'm using [this (excellent) flowchart diagram designer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4) in my application, but I'd like to use it as a `UserControl`.

To convert the `Application` into a `UserControl` I've changed the only window the application had:

```
<Window x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.Controls"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Diagram Designer"
    Height="850" Width="1000">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="DesignerCanvasContextMenu">
      ...
    </ContextMenu>
  </Window.Resources>
  ...
</Window>
```

into an user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DiagramDesigner.DiagramDesignerWPFControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:s="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner"
     xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.Controls"
     Height="850" Width="1000">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DesignerCanvasContextMenu">
         ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ...
</UserControl>
```

I took the `ResourceDicctionary` from the contents of `App.xaml` and added it to the control. Then I deleted the `App.xaml` file, as it can't be used in `Class Library` compilations.

---

**My problem is**:

When I add that new `User Control` to a WPF Form in another project, I can run the new application, I can add chart components and move them, but when I join/link the following exception raises:

> Cannot find resource named '{SolidBorderBrush}'. Resource names are case sensitive.

What am I doing wrong with the resources or their location in my `User Control`?

---

**Edition after accepting the answer:**

The risen exception also pointed to a line where the '{SolidBorderBrush}' was called. I didn't initially put it in this question, as it was a call and  not a declaration. This is the piece of code which linked the exception:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
   <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ToolbarSelectedBackgroundBrush}" />
   <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: You said that you took the ResourceDictionary from App.xaml, but you don't say where you put it. More on resource dictionaries, what they are and how to use them: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx (see especially [Resources are Declared at Different Scopes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx#resources))

Comment: Oh, I put it in the `UserControl`. It can be seen in the code I pasted. I'll fix the question to be more clair.

Comment: My bad... I didn't look at the code closely enough.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders There is no C#-3.5 tag.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. - Your question doesn't really having anything to do with C# anyway. Nothing would change (question or answer) if you were developing in VB or F#.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 You are right. I tagged it with [C#] due to my inexperience.

Comment: That's because there's no C# 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing here, because your question doesn't actually show any of the code which seems to be causing the issue, but you probably need to use `DynamicResource`.

```
{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}
```

You can only use StaticResource under very particular circumstances. You get a big performance boost most of the time, but it's very easy to end up in a situation where it can't be used (which may be what has happened).

Comment: You guessed right! The problem came from the `StaticResource` declaration of _SolidBorderBrush_. No I'll have to change most (if not all) `StaticResource` declarations to `DynamicResource` in the project. Thank you!